# where is my bitcoin?

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info

I recently wanted to get some bitcoins from someone.
I use blockchain and I clicked on receive and copied my bitcoins receivng address and gave it to someone.
then he bought some bitcoins(150$) from http://oraclechange.com/ and payed by paypal.
so he payed 150$ 1 hour ago and there is nothing in my blockchain wallet.
where are my bits?
(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: 15 views but no answers :|

Comment: How can we know?

Comment: what happened to my bits?

Comment: There is absolutely no way we could know. Have the person who paid figure it out by contacting the provider they used.

Comment: You have to ask your friend. When he bought the bitcoin, it went into his own wallet. He has to send those to your address. Maybe he can't? Maybe he won't?

Comment: he doesnt have bitcoin wallet.he bought it from that site by paypal.I have the reciept,too

Comment: https://blockchain.info/address/16KVqqvPyrQUZbS3Kd2nAcYJgPQxE4nDrk

Comment: Clearly, no bitcoin payment has been made to that address. You should talk to whoever was supposed to make the payment.

Comment: the money is back to my friend!again he tried and it was successful!